# How can I upload and optimize up to 165 pictures from any camera using PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have been stuck on this problem for almost 2 weeks now, trying to figure out how best to write a PHP script that would enable the user to click on a browse button, select up to 165 pictures from their camera, and then click 'Upload' to upload the selected pictures to the server. Each picture would be optimized whilst being uploaded, in order to make the heavily-pixel-ed images load fast in browser.

The HTML Form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="image_upload_form">
<input name="image_upload_box[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /> 
</form>
```

The PHP Script:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","200000000"); // for large images so that we do not get "Allowed memory exhausted"
ini_set('max_execution_time', 720); //720 seconds = 12 minutes

// upload the file
if((isset($_POST["submitted_form"])) and ($_POST["submitted_form"]=="image_upload_form")){
    $pic=$_FILES["image_upload_box"];
    $executionSuccessful=false;

    /* iterate through the posted images */
    foreach($pic['name'] as $f=>$name){
        $type=$pic["type"][$f];

        // file needs to be jpg,gif,bmp,x-png and 4 MB max
        if(($type=="image/jpeg" or $type=="image/pjpeg" or $type=="image/gif" 
        or $type=="image/x-png") and ($pic["size"][$f] < 4000000)){     

            // maximum upload width and height
            $max_upload_width=2592;
            $max_upload_height=1944;

            // if uploaded image was JPG/JPEG
            if($type=="image/jpeg" or $type=="image/pjpeg"){    
                $image_source=imagecreatefromjpeg($pic["tmp_name"][$f]);
            }

            // if uploaded image was GIF
            if($type=="image/gif"){ 
                $image_source=imagecreatefromgif($pic["tmp_name"][$f]);
            }

            // BMP doesn't seem to be supported so remove it form above image type test (reject bmps)   
            // if uploaded image was BMP
            if($type=="image/bmp"){ 
                $image_source=imagecreatefromwbmp($pic["tmp_name"][$f]);
            }

            // if uploaded image was PNG
            if($type=="image/x-png"){
                $image_source=imagecreatefrompng($pic["tmp_name"][$f]);
            }

            $remote_file="image_files/".$pic["name"][$f];
            imagejpeg($image_source,$remote_file,100);
            chmod($remote_file,0644);

            // get width and height of original image
            list($image_width,$image_height)=getimagesize($remote_file);

            if($image_width>$max_upload_width or $image_height >$max_upload_height){
                $proportions=$image_width/$image_height;

                if($image_width>$image_height){
                    $new_width=$max_upload_width;
                    $new_height=round($max_upload_width/$proportions);
                }       
                else{
                    $new_height=$max_upload_height;
                    $new_width=round($max_upload_height*$proportions);
                }
                $new_image=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width , $new_height);
                $image_source=imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);

                imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image_source,0,0,0,0,$new_width,
                $new_height,$image_width,$image_height);
                imagejpeg($new_image,$remote_file,100);         
                imagedestroy($new_image);
            }

            /* delete original image after optimizing */
            imagedestroy($image_source);        
            $executionSuccessful=true;
        }
        else $executionSuccessful=false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I keep running into issues with the either the number of images being uploaded, or the heavy-pixel nature of the pictures being uploaded, or worse, php script execution timeout...

As you can see from the PHP script, I have attempted to increase the memory limit and maximum execution time.
I also made some direct edits in the PHP.ini, changing post_max_size=2000M and upload_max_filesize=2001M.

Between these settings, the script above was finally able to upload and optimize only 20 pictures in 172 seconds, which goes nowhere in accomplishing the 165 uploads I need the script for.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work?

I Just applied the process described by Dubas, and implemented a neat jQuery ajax multi-upload script I found online. It's client side is perfect, but the server side is where I'm encountering problems. The script does not optimize, it simply uploads the pictures as they are (4MB, etc). And so I incorporated optimization code into it. The problem is, when I run it with optimization, some of the selected pictures are lost in the process (select 10 pix, and find that only about 7 of them were uploaded and optimized, the rest gone). However, if I run it without my optimization code, then everything works perfectly; select 10 pictures, and 10 pictures will be uploaded (but not optimized) at their full pixels. Therefore it begs the question that there is something wrong with my optimization code. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Code below:

```
session_start();
ini_set("memory_limit","200000000"); // for large images so that we do not get "Allowed memory exhausted"
ini_set('max_execution_time', 720); //720 seconds = 12 minutes

$allowed=array('png', 'jpg', 'gif');
if(isset($_FILES['upl']) and $_FILES['upl']['error']==0){
    $extension=pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension),$allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    $pic=$_FILES['upl'];
    $picName=$pic['name'];

    //if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$pic['name'])){
    if(uploadAndResizeImage($pic)){
        /* database properties for web server */      

            $dbHost='localhost';
            $dbPass='';
            $dbUser='root';
            $dbName='catscript_homeworks';

        /* start up a PDO database connection */
        $dsn="mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8;port=3306";
        $attrEmulatePrepares=PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES;
        $db=new PDO($dsn,$dbUser,$dbPass,array($attrEmulatePrepares=>false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

        $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        $tbl='gallery';
        $pic='file_upload/uploads/'.$picName;

        $sql=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO $tbl (pic,timestamp) VALUES (:pic,NOW())");
        $sql->execute(array('pic'=>$pic));

        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;


function uploadAndResizeImage($pic){
    $result=false;
    // file needs to be jpg,gif,bmp,x-png and 4 MB max
    if (($pic["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $pic["type"] == "image/pjpeg" 
    || $pic["type"] == "image/gif" || $pic["type"] == "image/x-png") && ($pic["size"] < 5000000)){

        // some settings
        $max_upload_width=1024;
        $max_upload_height=768;

        // if uploaded image was JPG/JPEG
        if($pic["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $pic["type"] == "image/pjpeg"){  
            $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($pic["tmp_name"]);
        }       
        // if uploaded image was GIF
        if($pic["type"] == "image/gif"){    
            $image_source = imagecreatefromgif($pic["tmp_name"]);
        }   
        // BMP doesn't seem to be supported so remove it form above image type test (reject bmps)   
        // if uploaded image was BMP
        if($pic["type"] == "image/bmp"){    
            $image_source = imagecreatefromwbmp($pic["tmp_name"]);
        }           
        // if uploaded image was PNG
        if($pic["type"] == "image/x-png"){
            $image_source = imagecreatefrompng($pic["tmp_name"]);
        }

        $remote_file = "uploads/".$pic["name"];
        imagejpeg($image_source,$remote_file,100);
        chmod($remote_file,0644);

        // get width and height of original image
        list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($remote_file);

        if($image_width>$max_upload_width || $image_height >$max_upload_height){
            $proportions = $image_width/$image_height;

            if($image_width>$image_height){
                $new_width = $max_upload_width;
                $new_height = round($max_upload_width/$proportions);
            }       
            else{
                $new_height = $max_upload_height;
                $new_width = round($max_upload_height*$proportions);
            }       


            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width , $new_height);
            $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);

            imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image_source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
            imagejpeg($new_image,$remote_file,100);

            imagedestroy($new_image);
        }
        imagedestroy($image_source);

        $result=true;
    }

    return $result;
};
```

Comment: Probably the two minutes is the maximun wait time of the HTTP server that host the PHP script.

Comment: It is recommended to optimize the pictures in background (using a cronjob) - even Youtube is optimizing the videos in background..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no "good" idea of how to do it in the manner you are doing it.

Probably a change of focus will be good to solve the problem.

For the server side is better to upload one by one. Create an script for upload one image and process it returning a flag when its done.

On client side select all files to be uploaded and use javascript with ajax calls to call the server side one by one instead of all at once. Also with this method you could put a checklist or progressbar in the client side to inform the user of the process status like "12 of 165 processed...."

Also if the process is too heavy and your server permits to perform cron processes you should store the images only and process in background later

- [JQuery upload component examples](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) (One of lots possibilities)

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look at those utilities; Thanks!